# mySQL function to check column value and perform new action

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to write a function within mySQL that checks the value of a SELECT query, and if it != 0, continue running the function and add to the result array?

I have a few entries marked as `related_id` = `0`  The rest have actual positive numbers attached.

I am trying to create a single query that will continually loop through a sql function, check and see if the retrieved `related_id` result is 0.  If not, then it will run again, add the newly checked row to the result array and continue until it finds a 0.

The way the DB is set up, a 0 will always occur, and it will be searching via id,so there should only be one result.

I am using a slightly modified tagging system.

```
keywords_id | keyword  | related_id
------------------------------------
1           | sports   | 0
2           | baseball | 1
3           | football | 1
4           | pitchers | 2
```

If I pass in `related_id` = `2` I'm looking to return an array that yields:

```
array 
[0]
   keyword => 'sports'
   keywords_id => '1'
   related_id => '0'
[1]
   keyword => 'baseball'
   keywords_id => '2'
   related_id => '1'
[2]
   keyword => 'pitcher'
   keywords_id => '4'
   related_id => '2'
```

I tried my luck with using IF and THEN but i just haven't seen enough examples and its tough to find solid tutorials online. Thanks!

```
SELECT k.* 
FROM keywords k
WHERE keywords_id = 2
```

The above query would essentially start it off. The `keywords_id` is the `related_id` that is passed.  Therefore the above would return `keywords_id: 2 |keyword: baseball |related_id: 1`

Because related_id 1 is NOT 0, i would need to run it again.

I realize this can be done in PHP through a few extra queries...is that the way I should do this?  I assume it could be done in mySQL after reading about functions.  I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Can you post the query you have tried? might be helpful to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I added as much as I could.  I acknowledged that this could be done through multiple queries and php rather easily.  So the answer could take that question into scope as well.

Comment: Are you searching for a stored procedure?

Comment: ^i'm not quite sure. I looked up stored procedure, it seems like it uses something outside mySQLs function command.  The reason I am asking this questions i mainly because I have no knowledge of functions inside mysql, and thus no experience using it.  I'm not even sure if its possible.

Comment: Sorry my main problem is that I don't understand what you really searching for. (I don't have at least information about your db structure) Thatswhy I cannot give an example. but it sounds like it can be done either with a regular query or a stored procedure. I would suggest google on this and start with 'hello world' like examples.

Comment: Hi Ricky, once you run the function and the result isn't 0, what determines what value you should plug in next for the 'keywords_id' column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support returning an array from a function. Would suggest creating a table (or possibly a temporary table) to hold the results and then writing a stored procedure to populate it instead.

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but maybe something along the lines of this?

```
CREATE TABLE results (keywords_id INT, keyword VARCHAR(2000), related_id INT);

CREATE PROCEDURE populateResults(IN keyword_id_in INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE num_results INT;
  DECLARE max_results INT;
  DECLARE next_keyword_id INT;
  SET next_keyword_id = keyword_id_in;
  SET max_results = 5;
  SET num_results = 0;

  DELETE FROM results;

  the_loop: LOOP
    INSERT INTO results
    SELECT keywords_id, keyword, related_id
    FROM keywords
    WHERE keywords_id = next_keyword_id;

    SELECT related_id
    FROM keywords
    WHERE keywords_id = next_keyword_id
    INTO next_keyword_id;

    IF (next_keyword_id = 0) || (num_results >= max_results) THEN
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
    SET num_results = num_results + 1;
  END LOOP the_loop;
END
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3e82/1)

Comment: Very cool stuff.  Haven't been able to test it yet.  But just the design itself is very informative.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from above sample - need to get all records checked until a match is found ( the above sample for related_id = 2 ).

If so you can try using mysql cursors http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html
in order to loop the result set.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting stuff